# How the client side looks like in meteor or derby

Tags: node.js, meteor, client-side, derbyjs

I have been looking around at those cool new node.js frameworks (mostly derby).
They both seem to be isomorphic frameworks... Which if I understand correctly means you 'can use the same code for server and client'.

So how does it affects the technologies you use on the client side?

For example, I guess backbone is unnecessary with those frameworks... Right?
On the other hand you can still benifit from stuff like jquery ui, or bootstrap maybe??

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some work with Meteor, and I can tell you that the libraries like jquery and  Backbone are still very useful (almost essential).
As the docs says: 
"Embrace the Ecosystem. Meteor is open source and integrates, rather than replaces, existing open source tools and frameworks.". That is really true, you only need to adjust your code to fit the Meteor reactive programming style. 
I really recommend you Meteor over Derby.

Comment: Thanks. Can you maybe elaborate on how backbone's MVC would fits together with meteor's model-view binding?

Comment: I would also like to know why you prefer meteor over derby... But I guess I should open another question for that.

Comment: This is a decent read on the derby / meteor debate.http://blog.derbyjs.com/2012/04/14/our-take-on-derby-vs-meteor/

Comment: Thanks, I read it. There is very little info on the web about Derby. So I think I read pretty much everything google can find...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use Backbone because both of these frameworks have routers and templates.
You can use jQuery UI, Backbone and any other client-side libraries with these frameworks.

P.s.: I got experience with Meteor and Derby and I would recommend you Derby over Meteor.